# git blame for a file which has been renamed many times

Tags: git, rename, blame

When I use `git blame`, a very time-spending situation is that the file has been renamed for many times, the `blame` will point me to the SHA of the recent rename commit. I then need to blame on the rename version, if the file has been renamed multiple times, I need to blame multiple times.

What I need to find with `blame` is the real author of a line of code when it is first written. Commit of `git mv` is not what I am looking for

Is there a way to let `blame` go beyond the renaming commits?

Or at least, is there a git command that can directly list how many times a file has been renamed? With this history I can manually bisect to find the appropriate version to blame, instead of go all the way from end to beginning.

Comment: This is no guaranteed way to do this, because sometimes Git cannot track files across renames (but, sometimes it _can_).  Best practice is to avoid renaming and moving files.  Or at least, you should aim to do it very sparingly.

Comment: For a large cooperating project, the rename history cannot be controlled by me